# Importing Anything in a Module Leads to 'Cannot resolve symbol' Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jar

I simply wanted to create a Jar archive (.jar file) out of my classes using Android Studio. To do so, I created a module using **File > New > New Module > Java Library**. Then I wrote two classes (LocationAndroidPlugin, MyLocationService) in the module:

[image]

But Android Studio complains that it cannot resolve the import statements in the classes:

[image]

I tried **File > Invalidate Cache** in vain.

My Android Studio version is:
Android Studio 2.3.1
Build #AI-162.3871768, built on April 1, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use **Java Library** option if you want to use serviceConnection, activity, or intent because it does not have Android classes. Instead, you must create the new module as an **Android Library** from **File > New > New Module > Android Library**.

Comment: My settings.gradle is this: `include ':app', ':libzerokeylocationservice'`

Comment: so did you define 

`compile project(':libzerokeylocationservice')`

in build.gradle under your app folder?

Comment: Which build.gradle? As you know there are couple of them. Do you mean the build for project or for app module or for libzerokeylocationservice module? "compile project(...)" does not exist in any of them.

Comment: i mean for app module.

Comment: No. It's not defined there.

Comment: can you define it and rebuild your project i think it will work after this step

Comment: After adding it, it gives error:  Error:(23, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'project()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'LocationServiceUnityPlugin' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).

Comment: hi again, here is a problem with java library. if you want to use serviceConnection, activity, or intent you must import new module as a android library from File > New > New Module > Android Library. because of java has not android classes, you couldn't import them.

Comment: @ Umut Aksun, Yes that's correct. I should have created an Android Library instead of Java Library. Once I created Android Library, everything worked and I did not need to add 'compile build' or to do anything else. Please modify your original answer and I will accept it as the answer.